# How can I override a Drupal contrib module's method?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I need to extend a mailchimp_signup module so that the form fields show placeholders.

Fields are rendered in class MailchimpSignupPageForm method buildForm by calling mailchimp_insert_drupal_form_tag method. This function is in mailchimp.module file, and I would like to add the placeholder attribute to it without overriding it. What's the best way to do this?

I can't manage to make it work by using my_module_insert_drupal_form_tag in either the theme directory or a custom module.

Answer (score 0):

your `my_module_insert_drupal_form_tag` function does not work because that is not a hook.
Since it is just a form you are trying to alter, the [HOOK_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x) or even better, the [HOOK_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.2.x) are probably what you want to use.
These hooks can be used to alter any forms on the site.
You should be able to just set the placeholder attribute on any of the elements you want from within these hooks.

Comment: Thanks 2pha, I thought that was the case but didn't know how to tell if a function is implemented as a hook. How can you know that? Regarding your solution, how can I tell what is the form_id? This is a form created by a custom module, and it doesn't appear in admin/structure/webform The machine code name found in admin/config/services/mailchimp/signup doesn't seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: You can search for HOOKS on the drupal api site. For custom modules, they will often have an api readme file, or you can look in the code. The 3rd paramater to HOOK_form_alter is the form ID, usually I will implement this function and output the form id, then change the function to HOOK_form_FORM_ID_alter using the id that was just output.